# Holding Havdala Candle

Tags: shabbat, havdalah

Is there *any* reason outside of practicality that one would need to hold a havdala candle? (Someone asked the question based on havdala sets having a candle holder)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40825/height-of-havdalah-candle-height-of-spouse

Comment: @rosends thanks for the related question, that would've been my follow-up if this one produces any real results

Answer (score 3):

The Shulchan Aruch in 298 -  [סימן רחצ - דיני נר הבדלה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0056_L2) - lists 15 Halachot regarding the Havdala candle - and yet does not mention the need to hold it.

Even the fact that it's held is not mentioned.

Ditto for the [Aruch HaShulchan in 298](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html). In his 18  Halachot does not mention holding it.

Ditto for the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן צו - דיני תפלת ערבית ודיני הבדלה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0095_L2)

Ditto for the קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף in  [סימן רצו - דיני הבדלה על היין](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_23.html#HtmpReportNum0053_L2)

Yet, all of the above mention holding the Besamin (spices) during Havdala. Conclusion - it does **not** need to be held, except for practical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

[Halachipedia - Fire](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Havdalah) points out that there are poskim that allow an electric light to be used for the havdallah *candle*. Even those who oppose this do not use the fact that it is not held as one of the reasons.

> Some poskim allow one to use an electric light in place of a Havdala candle
> in a time of need.[21] In fact, it is reported that
> Rabbi Chaim Ozer Grodzinsky would always use an electric bulb for
> Havdala in order to demonstrate how strongly he felt that electricity
> is to be treated exactly like fire from the perspective of
> halacha.[22]
>
> Nevertheless, there are those authorities who discourage the use of an
> electric light for Havdala. Among their opposition to is the
> fact that the blessing recited upon the Havdala candle includes the
> word "fire" which seems to imply the need for actual fire, not merely
> light. As such a light bulb would not be acceptable according to this
> view.[23] Even among the authorities who permit the use of electric
> lighting when needed many would disqualify the use of fluorescent
> bulbs as they work differently than standard light bulbs. [24]
>
> [21] Shaarim Metzuyanim Behalachah 96:6, Az Nidberu 8:2, Rivevot Ephraim 3:599. see also Mishpitei Uziel OC 1:9
> [22] Shaarim Metzuyanim Behalachah 96:6. Sh"t Nachalat Shimon 15 says this was the practice of Rav Chaim Soloveitchik
> [23] Har Tzvi 2:114, Sh"t Yechave Daat 2:39, Maharshag 2:107, Kitzur S"A of Rabbi Raphael Baruch Toledano pg. 323
> [24] Hachashmal L’or Hahalacha 3:88

---

I know of havdala candles that are big enough to stand on the table themselves without having to be in a holder. They are often too big to be held as they are used. I have been using one that I purchased in Tzfat for the past several decades. I have seen them being used without being held in different homes.

The free standing ones that I have used and many of the ones that I have see, are too wide to be held. The way they were described in the store at Tzfat and elsewhere, was that they either could not be or did not need to be held.

There are a number of these that can be found on line.

As examples, [havdalah candles free standing](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=havdalah+candles+free+standing&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Ahavdalah+candles+free+standing), [Havdalah Candle - Free Standing Purple](https://www.jewishbazaar.com/havdalah-candle-purple-free-standing.htm), and [Free Standing 18 Wick Havdallah Candle](https://www.alljudaica.com/Free-Standing-18-Wick-Havdallah-Candle-p/14542.htm)

Comment: There is a common minhag to use a twisted candle. Unless you put them in a holder, these would have to be held. IMO, Most of these candles are too long to stay in the holder without tipping over, anyway. At least, until they have melted down about halfway.

Comment: The reason for the twisted candle is in order to have the multiple wicks set up properly. That is a practical matter not a matter of the minhag being to hold them. That is what the OP was asking and why I answered that it does not have to be held for other than the practical reason. I showed examples of kinds that do not have to be held to prove this.

Comment: But you could hold an electric lamp...

Comment: @mevaqesh the question was **must** you hold the havdallah candle, not **could** you hold it. I gave examples of havdallah candles that are spoken of in terms of not being held. Electric light in the ceiling fixture, large base candle that is too wide to be held which are shown as used for havdallah. If one must hold it, the discussions would have mentioned that.

Comment: "I gave examples of havdallah candles that are spoken of in terms of not being held." No you didn't. There is no proof that any of this need not be held.

Comment: @mevaqesh the point was that the discussion of electric lights was lo plug and included all kinds which would include those that could not be held. Similarly those free standing, as I saw in Tzfat included those too big to hold during havdallah.

Comment: These are two discrete points. As to the first, it is quite week. It's like saying that a discussion about whether the candle needs to be braided indicates whether it needs to be freestanding. Since a source says braided is okay, then it's a lo plug and works freestanding. This is silly. One aspect of something being permissible ha absolutely nothing to do with other aspects which are irrelevant to the question and not discussed

Comment: Regarding the second point, it is also quite weak. Since you saw something sold online it must be ritually acceptable?? Since some unnamed people did something it must be okay?

Comment: No. A discussion on if it must be braided would then imply that it must be braided whether free standing or not. If it must be held is a totally different discussion. I said that I saw free standing candles in tzfat that were accepted as valid there. Also the electric discussion included ceiling lights which could not be held.

Comment: @mevaquesh I should say that the online candles were just examples of candles of that type. The candles in Tzfat were actually shown to me and used when I was there in 1967 and 1988. I also have seen candles of the type that were not held in the homes of various musmachim recently, besides using them myself. However, I did not mention that in the answer as it would not prove anything.