# Dating and Havdala candle

Tags: shabbat, mysticism-kabbalah, havdalah, shidduchim-dating

I've heard people talking about the merit of a good relationship with his shidduch in dating from the act of holding the Havdala candle. How does the two relate?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40825

Comment: "a good relationship with his shidduch in dating": you mean a good relationship, while dating, with his date?

Comment: Yes,  and it does not relate with the link because i have read somewhere in Chabad about a kabbalistic explaination of the same.  However that wasn't enough information :)